# CGAffineTransform Does Not Work With CGRect

Tags: swift, swift5, cgaffinetransform, cgrect

CGAffineTransform does not transform CGRect.

My code:

```swift
        var rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 300, height: 300)
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
        rect.applying(transform)
```

x,y should be 60, however,they stay the same (20,20) after transform is applied. This is evident both in `print(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y)` and in the image I'm cropping with rect.

What am I missing?

Comment: The `x` and `y` point to the origin of the rect. It looks like the origin of the rect is invariant to scaling.

Comment: Can you elaborate, why is it so and how to fix it?

Comment: @mezzi Why don't you transform the actual view that contains the frame "rect" ?

Comment: Just ran this in a playground and got 60/60/900/900

Comment: That’s why i downvoted it. It’s not a mutating method so this question isn’t helpful.

Comment: @badhanganesh I'm using this rect to crop an image. But it's not the point. CGAffineTransform should work on CGRect regardless.

Comment: @Jessy You should write an answer about that.

Comment: I should not! This is a bad use of all of our time! But I did.

Comment: @Jessy This is a noob question, but it's a good question. There's code, sample input, expected ouput, and actual output. I see a problem here: why isn't there a warning about the unused result of `CGRect.applying(_:)`? It's likely marked `@discardableResult`, but it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[applying](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1455875-applying) is not mutating. You didn't reassign.

```swift
rect = rect.applying(transform)
```